# Creating a development instance of a large production RDS instance

Tags: amazon-rds

We have a large RDS instance in AWS (100GB). We're creating a script which will clear out old data in the database at regular intervals. In order to test this fully we'd like to setup a copy of the existing production RDS instance which we can use to test the script on (so we don't lose data from the production instance).

Is there a way to create a standalone duplicate RDS instance based on another instance? I had thought I could do this by using a snapshot, but it appears you can only restore an instance from a snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a snapshot you can restore to a different/new instance name. E.g. create a snapshot of `database-one` then restore the snapshot to a different instance name `database-one-copy`.

I use this method programmatically to create a development database on a nightly schedule or as needed using the python AWS SDK Boto3 and this method https://github.com/airsciences/aws-rds-persist.